# In this sql*plus query what do ( ) and " " mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do we use these symbols in a query of sql*plus, 
e.g.

```
select ename, sal, round(sal*2/365) "dailysal" from emp;
```

What do the symbols `()` and `""` mean?

Comment: Tried to improve the English grammatically--I think this is what you were meaning to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Round brackets `()` bounds the parameters to a function. In your particular example `"round"` is a funtion that takes the expression `"sal*2/365"` as an argument. `"dailysal"` defines how the resulting column (the one which would hold the values of `round(sal*2/365)` evaluation) would be named. So when executed your resulting table would look like this:

```
  +------+------+----------+ 
  |ename | sal  | dailysal |
  +------+------+----------+ 
  | John | 1000 |     5    |
  +------+------+----------+ 
  | ...  | .... |   ...    |
```

Without "dailysal" your result would look like

```
  +------+------+-----------------+ 
  |ename | sal  | round(sal*2/365)|
  +------+------+-----------------+ 
  | John | 1000 |        5        |
  +------+------+-----------------+ 
  | ...  | .... |       ...       |
```